# Ryu-controller for Mininet network configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdn, mininet, ryu

I'm studing about a ring topology of network in mininet. There are 3 access point, in a triangle configuration: ap1, ap2 and ap3 that are connected each other. There is a station (sta1) that isn't mobile (always connected to ap3) and there is a mobile station (sta2) that moves randomly betweeen ap1 and ap2.
The scope is to ping sta2 from sta1.
I used a stp ryu-controller to avoid broadcast storm. It doesn't work well beacause for example I can ping sta2 when it is connected to ap1, but when it moves to ap2, I can't ping it anymore. How can I solve this problem? I attach my ryu-code:

```
    <---sta2--->
  ap1---------ap2
   -           -
    -        - 
      - ap3 -
        sta1

from ryu.base import app_manager
from ryu.controller import ofp_event
from ryu.controller.handler import CONFIG_DISPATCHER, MAIN_DISPATCHER
from ryu.controller.handler import set_ev_cls
from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_3
from ryu.lib import dpid as dpid_lib
from ryu.lib import stplib
from ryu.lib.packet import packet
from ryu.lib.packet import ethernet
from ryu.app import simple_switch_13


class SimpleSwitch13(simple_switch_13.SimpleSwitch13):
    OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION]
    _CONTEXTS = {'stplib': stplib.Stp}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleSwitch13, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mac_to_port = {}
        self.stp = kwargs['stplib']

        # Sample of stplib config.
        #  please refer to stplib.Stp.set_config() for details.
        config = {dpid_lib.str_to_dpid('0000000000000001'):
                  {'bridge': {'priority': 0x8000}},
                  dpid_lib.str_to_dpid('0000000000000002'):
                  {'bridge': {'priority': 0x9000}},
                  dpid_lib.str_to_dpid('0000000000000003'):
                  {'bridge': {'priority': 0xa000}}}
        self.stp.set_config(config)

    def delete_flow(self, datapath):
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        for dst in self.mac_to_port[datapath.id].keys():
            match = parser.OFPMatch(eth_dst=dst)
            mod = parser.OFPFlowMod(
                datapath, command=ofproto.OFPFC_DELETE,
                out_port=ofproto.OFPP_ANY, out_group=ofproto.OFPG_ANY,
                priority=1, match=match)
            datapath.send_msg(mod)

    @set_ev_cls(stplib.EventPacketIn, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _packet_in_handler(self, ev):
        msg = ev.msg
        datapath = msg.datapath
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
        in_port = msg.match['in_port']

        pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)
        eth = pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]

        dst = eth.dst
        src = eth.src

        dpid = datapath.id
        self.mac_to_port.setdefault(dpid, {})

        self.logger.info("packet in %s %s %s %s", dpid, src, dst, in_port)

        # learn a mac address to avoid FLOOD next time.
        self.mac_to_port[dpid][src] = in_port

        if dst in self.mac_to_port[dpid]:
            out_port = self.mac_to_port[dpid][dst]
        else:
            out_port = ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD

        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]

        # install a flow to avoid packet_in next time
        if out_port != ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD:
            match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst)
            self.add_flow(datapath, 1, match, actions)

        data = None
        if msg.buffer_id == ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER:
            data = msg.data

        out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id,
                                  in_port=in_port, actions=actions, data=data)
        datapath.send_msg(out)

    @set_ev_cls(stplib.EventTopologyChange, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _topology_change_handler(self, ev):
        dp = ev.dp
        dpid_str = dpid_lib.dpid_to_str(dp.id)
        msg = 'Receive topology change event. Flush MAC table.'
        self.logger.debug("[dpid=%s] %s", dpid_str, msg)

        if dp.id in self.mac_to_port:
            self.delete_flow(dp)
            del self.mac_to_port[dp.id]

    @set_ev_cls(stplib.EventPortStateChange, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _port_state_change_handler(self, ev):
        dpid_str = dpid_lib.dpid_to_str(ev.dp.id)
        of_state = {stplib.PORT_STATE_DISABLE: 'DISABLE',
                    stplib.PORT_STATE_BLOCK: 'BLOCK',
                    stplib.PORT_STATE_LISTEN: 'LISTEN',
                    stplib.PORT_STATE_LEARN: 'LEARN',
                    stplib.PORT_STATE_FORWARD: 'FORWARD'}
        self.logger.debug("[dpid=%s][port=%d] state=%s",
                          dpid_str, ev.port_no, of_state[ev.port_state])
```

Answer (score 0):

### What I believe is causing the issue

I believe that the reason as to why `sta2` is able to ping `sta1` initially is because the flow tables in the OpenFlow Switch are empty. When `sta2` pings `sta1`, the controller adds the flow into the `OVSSwitch`, and thus creates a flow entry in the flow table.

Due to this entry in the flow table, the two stations are able to ping each other since the location is known and a route is set. Once the station migrates to `ap2`, there is no new flow entry created and attached to the flow table. Why? Because the controller believes that the flow entry in the flow table is accurate and as such does not need to query the network for the path again.

### A method to verify this claim

This can be verified by using the `dpctl` functionality provided by the mininet console. I'm using a slightly different network architecture below, but my theory still holds.

[sta5 migrates to ap1 from ap3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvfv2.png)

In this case, `sta5` was initially present in `ap3`, and we could ping `sta3`, which is present in `ap2` in the initial state of mobility when `sta5` is still associated with `ap3``.

[sta5 pings sta3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY4ly.png)

Running `dpctl dump-flows` allows us to see that the flows have been added after the initial ping has been made.

[dpctl dump-flows response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysCnU.png)

Now, once `sta5` migrates to `ap1`, you'll notice that the ping fails and that the flows have not been altered, thus proving my statement above.

[sta5 has migrated to ap1 and fails to ping sta3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnUjI.png)

### Possible solutions

Coming to what can be done to alleviate this problem, there are a few methods,

1. Ad-hoc your way through it and `dpctl del-flows` the station which is migrating.
2. Develop a script to dissociate flows once the station leaves the AP range.
3. Develop a script to dissociate flows of the station in the switch when it enters a new AP range.

I realize that this is a pretty late response, but hope that it helps out the people that end up facing this issue later on.